# Composing meta-functions

Tags: c++, templates, function, metaprogramming, composition

Is there an established idiom for composing ("chaining") meta-functions? This is my current solution:

```
template
<
    template <typename> class First,
    template <typename> class Then,
    typename T
>
struct compose : Then<typename First<T>::type> {};
```

And here is an example usage:

```
template <typename T>
struct remove_cv : compose<remove_const, remove_volatile, T> {};
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might check out the boost::mpl library:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/composition-and-argument-binding.html

I'm not claiming that mpl is better than what you have.  Just that it looks like similar territory and it might interest you.